# substr md5 collision

Tags: hash, md5, substr, hash-collision

I need a 4-character hash. At the moment I am taking the first 4 characters of a `md5()` hash. I am hashing a string which is 80 characters long or less. Will this lead to collision? or, what is the chance of collision, assuming I'll hash less than 65,536 (16<sup>4</sup>) different elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Surprisingly high indeed.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) As you can see from [this graph of an approximate collision probability](http://goo.gl/fywl7) (formula from the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)), with just a few hundred elements your probability of having a collision is over 50%.

Note, of course, if you're facing the possibility of an attacker providing the string, you can probably assume that it's 100% - scanning to find a collision in a 16-bit search space can be done almost instantaneously on any modern PC. Or even any modern cell phone, for that matter.

Answer (score 7):

Well, each character of `md5` is a hex bit.  That means it can have one of 16 possible values.  So if you're only using the first 4 "hex-bits", that means you can have `16 * 16 * 16 * 16` or `16^4` or 65536 or `2^16` possibilities.

So, that means that the total available "space" for results is only 16 bits wide.  Now, according to the [Birthday Attack/Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack), there are the following chances for collision:

- `50%` chance -> `300` entries
- `1%` chance -> `36` entries
- `0.0000001%` chance -> `2` entries.

So there is quite a high chance for collisions.

Now, you say you need a 4 character hash.  Depending on the exact requirements, you can do:

- 4 hex-bits for `16^4` (65,536) possible values
- 4 alpha bits for `26^4` (456,976) possible values
- 4 alpha numeric bits for `36^4` (1,679,616) possible values
- 4 ascii printable bits for about `93^4` (74,805,201) possible values (assuming ASCII 33 -> 126)
- 4 full bytes for `256^4` (4,294,967,296) possible values.

Now, which you choose will depend on the actual use case.  Does the hash need to be transmitted to a browser?  How are you storing it, etc.

I'll give an example of each (In PHP, but should be easy to translate / see what's going on):

**4 Hex-Bits**:

```
$hash = substr(md5($data), 0, 4);
```

**4 Alpha bits**:

```
$hash = substr(base_convert(md5($data), 16, 26)0, 4);
$hash = str_replace(range(0, 9), range('S', 'Z'), $hash);
```

**4 Alpha Numeric bits**:

```
$hash = substr(base_convert(md5($data), 16, 36), 0, 4);
```

**4 Printable Assci Bits**:

```
$hash = hash('md5', $data, true); // We want the raw bytes
$out = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $out .= chr((ord($hash[$i]) % 93) + 33);
}
```

**4 full bytes**:

```
$hash = substr(hash('md5', $data, true), 0, 4); // We want the raw bytes
```

Comment: Just a quick bug fix, for your '4 Alpha bits' solution, I think the second line should be:

$hash = str_replace(range(0, 9), range('Q', 'Z'), $hash);

Comment: Come to think of it, the second one gives a-z + Q-Z as a range = 36 ^ 4 possible values. .. and the whole should read: $hash = substr(base_convert(md5($data), 16, 26),0, 4); $hash = str_replace(range(0, 9), range('q', 'z'), $hash);

Answer (score 0):

4 first characters contains 4*4 = 16 bits of data, so collision will be definitely at 65536 elements, and, due to birthday attack, it will be found much faster. You should use more bits of hash.

Comment: shouldn't you do 16^4 instead of 4*4 ? cause each characters have 16 variations and md5 uses Hex characters only

Comment: He's counting bits, not the count of possible values there.