# Unique ID with PHP

Tags: php, random

I write this simple line to get random & unique code each time (just 8 characters):

```
echo substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)),0,8);
```

**Output:**

077331e5
5af425b1
0fc7dcf2
...

I ask if I'll never get a collision (duplicate). Or that can happen.

**BS:** 
It's better to use `time()`?

```
echo substr(md5(uniqid(time(), true)),0,8);
```

Comment: Why in the heck are you `substr`ing `md5`? You **will** end up with dups for sure doing this. Just use `uniquid`

Comment: I want to display just 8 characters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hashes can have collisions. By taking a substring of the hash you are just upping the chance of that happening.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of what you feed into md5(), by doing the substring, you're eliminating a large part of md5's output and constricting the range of possible hashes. md5 outputs a 128bit string, and you're limiting it to 32bits, So you've got from a 1 in 1x10^38 to 1 in 4 billion chance of a collision.

Answer (score 2):

Your "unique code" is a string of eight hexadecimal digits, and thus it has 4294967296 possible values.  You are thus guanteed to get a duplicate of an earlier code by the 4294967297th time you run it.

Comment: Sooner than that I am afraid. A hash is a calculated result. All it would take is one other timeframe, treated as a string, hashing to the 8 character starting similar. You'd be better off grabbing a random value from the available stack of 4294967296.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a method to provide unique Ids called `uniqid()`

You stand a fair chance of your 8 char MD5 being unique but as with any random string the shorter you make the more likely you are to have a collision.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it can happen. There's a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681913/substr-md5-collision) about the collision space of MD5 that you might want to check out. Doing a substring of the MD5 will make the collision space much, much larger.

A better solution may be the answer proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307486/short-unique-id-in-php), possibly checking it against other unique IDs that you've generated.

Answer (score 1):

Your code returns part of a hash. Hashes are for hashing, thus you can not guarantee any pattern within the results (eg. uniqueness).

Also, you are getting only part of a hash, and each letter from a hash is hexadecimal (from `0` to `9` or from `a` to `b` - 16 possibilities). It needs only a simple calculation:

```
16 ^ 8 = 4 294 967 296
```

to find how many unique values can your code generate. This number (`4 294 967 296`) means, that if you use this function more thatn 4 294 967 296 times, the value generated with it **surely will not be unique**. Of course it is certain, that in this case the number of iterations will not be unique after applying it to smaller number of values.